# how to check if hadoop is tuned for job,

Tags: hadoop

I have a job (handles data of 4 GB) and I checked the CPU usage and memory usage they both are under 10%.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I believe his question is about how to check if his Hadoop cluster is configured correctly. His node is running below 10% usage, so he wants to know how he can see if his node is running at maximum efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your job most likely doesn't need more than that. You could try stress-testing your cluster with TeraSort (included in the examples jar), if your nodes are still operating at a very low amount of usage it may be a problem with your configuration.

Comment: you are right, sorry if my question was not clearThanks , I will check with teraSort

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop comes with Benchmark utility to verify Hadoop cluster settings.

Check Hadoop TestDFSIO.